# I can't have a global search in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

[image]

I'd like to have a global search for 'builder', but the command `GS: builder` doesn't work, and show me the Error:`lid: can't locate 'ID': No such file or directory` Something I lost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lid: can't locate 'ID': No such file or directory`: Before global search, there must generate an ID file. So I executed `:Update` in my project, I found `gawk` does not exist.

When I installed `gawk`, global search does work.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation claims](https://github.com/skwp/greplace.vim/blob/master/doc/greplace.txt#L68) that the plugin uses `:grep` internally and (rather obviously) the user-defined `'grepprg'`.

You appear to have set your `grepprg` to `lid` so you must make sure that:

- you are using it correctly,
- you performed [the right customization](https://github.com/skwp/greplace.vim#customization).